# how to show files in current directory with embedded php webserver (as command line)

Tags: php, bash, command-line, embeddedwebserver, working-directory

I want to run the simple embedded webserver from php via command line

```
php -S 0.0.0.0:8000
```

and let it show the content of the current directory.

As of the man page the only possible additional option to `-S` is `-t` for the document root. I know I can just create a `index.php` file with the following content

```
<html>
<body>
<?php
  $directory = "./";
  $files = glob($directory . "*");

  foreach($files as $file) {
    echo "<a href=".rawurlencode($file).">".basename($file)."</a><br>";
  }
?>
</body>
</html>
```

but I don’t want to create a file in that directory.

Isn’t it possible to run that code as a command line argument? I have tried it with the option `-r` and even with a virtual bash file and the `-F`-option as follows: `-F <(… php code here …)` but it seems true that the `-S` command only accepts `-t` as additional command.

Is there any trick to achieve it?

PS: I know that with python 2 or python 3 it is easily possible to show the current directory with python’s embedded webserver with

```
python -m SimpleHTTPServer   # python 2
python -m http.server        # python 3
```

but I want to do it with php.

Answer (score 1):

Replace `"./"` from the assignment of variable `$directory` with the complete path of the directory you want to serve. Or, even better, change it to:

```
$directory = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/';
```

to serve the path you provide as argument to `-t` in the command line.

Put `index.php` wherever you want in the file system and add its location (with complete path) to the end of the `php` command line.

If, for example, you save it as `/home/erik/index.php`, start PHP as:

```
php -S 0.0.0.0:8000 -t /home/erik/web /home/erik/index.php
```

PHP will use the script as a router. It will run it on every request and you can change it to interpret the request (`$_GET[]`, `$_SERVER[]`) and generate different output, depending of the requested path and query string.